# cool/génial/chouette/super

Tags: choix-de-mot

Would you say that each of the following words has a somewhat different meaning for example in the sentence below, or should they more or less be considered as synonyms?

> Ce film est vraiment **cool/génial/chouette/super**!

Merci d'avance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While they could all be used in that sentence to express that the film was enjoyed, they can have slightly different weight and meaning.

"cool" means the same as in the english word "cool", or "hip".

"génial" means "genius", or "awesome".

"chouette" means "nice", or "beautiful".

"super" means "great", or "very good".

When using these kinds of superlatives, the tone can have a lot of meaning to carry the weight of the praise that is behind the word. For example if the tone is very nonchalant, "ouais c'était cool" can mean simply "yeah it was ok". But if the tone is really emphatic, "Ah ouais c'était trop cool!!!!" can mean "Oh yes it was truly unique".